# Comparing two different leagues of similar but not equal distributions around a standard deviation of error of a prediction from a rating system

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, mathematical-statistics, games

This query ties a lot of my interests in rating sports teams together, because as I’ve mentioned before I do a version of the Kenneth Massey method (as per his 1997 thesis http://masseyratings.com/theory/massey97.pdf) of rating Sports Teams. I do it in Excel and usually do it by setting up a least squares based problem and either have the Solver application solve it, or setting up a conditional recursive loop (as this will provide two extra elements - average margin of victory and strength of schedule). This enables me to make projections of a predicted margin of victory in a match (by having the ratings for two teams and a Home Field/Court advantage). Because the standard deviation of the error of the prediction (against the actual score) is usually normally distributed (as per Stern “On the Probability of Winning a Football Game” American Statistician 45 (1991): 179-83) which can be virtually proved via a QQ plot amongst other things - it allows you to put percentages on projections (by taking the predicated margin of victory between the two teams from the ratings as a mean and the standard deviation as per the above).

My query is this, just before Christmas in the Spanish Asbol Handball League Barcelona were 15 wins with 0 losses and a derived rating of 10.88. The standard deviation of the error about the prediction was 4.1. In the Russian Superleague, Chehovski were also 15 wins with 0 losses and a derived rating of 13.97. The standard deviation of the error about the prediction was 4.4. Who would be the better team based on the approach above?

Can I or is there a way to compare two teams effectively from two different distributions? By this I am assuming that it would be unsound to assume that Chehovski is 3.09 points better on a neutral ground than Barcelona (e.g. 13.97 – 10.88). Is there a way to make a correction to adjust for the fact that the two leagues have a different distribution (I haven’t looked at these leagues over a couple of years yet, which I would normally do to get a more accurate standard deviation so currently I am assuming the standard deviations are different for the two different leagues and the 4.1 and 4.4 are approximately reflective after half a season).

In this case I am just keen to figure out who is effectively the best handball team statistically (and how you can effectively separate two teams in different leagues with the same record). Kenneth Massey in the ratings part of his site doesn’t treat leagues individually (and also refined his rating formula from his thesis so that it is bias free and not affected by points scored in the same way as Dr Wesley Colley’s approach http://www.colleyrankings.com/method.html).

I don’t have a great maths background (I just enjoy sports) so I would be keen for any nudges in the right direction as I'd like to find a mathematically sound way of doing this.

Comment: How can you hope to compare teams in different leagues? Suppose the best elementary school team is undefeated. In what sense do you want to say they are better than a mediocre professional team? If the two played, I would bet on the professional team to crush the kids.

Comment: They are both professional top division clubs, with international players on their rosters but in different countries - so quality of the teams isn't an issue. They are probably both in the top 10 clubs in the world currently. The only common form line I have between the two teams is they have both beaten the same Spanish club at their home ground by 14 points in the last 6 months so they are of equivalent strength. They standard a chance of meeting each other in the EHF Champions League later this year and I am just trying to figure who is the better club and put a number on it.